# AVMutableComposition play blank with AVPlayer but export fine with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I create an `AVMutableComposition` containing videos imported from the library. I pass an `AVMutableVideoComposition` containing an array of `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` in order to transform (scale, rotate) and fade (opacity) between video tracks.

With most videos no problem occurs. I can play the composition using `AVPlayer` or export it using `AVAssetExportSession` without any problem. But for some videos when the composition is passed to an `AVPlayer` I get a black screen like when the timing of the differents `AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction` are not set correctly. However when I export the exact same composition containing the exact same instruction and timing (actually the same composition) to an `AVAssetExportSession` the movie exports perfectly. If I play the imported video alone as simple AVAsset using the AVPlayer, the video play fine.

I tried to raise the time scale of my movie to 60000 instead of 600 hopping it was the duration of the imported video that was an issue (floating point being lost) but it is not the case.

It happens under iOS8 but may also happens under iOS7 I dont know.

PS: I didn't post code because there are far too many lines.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with AVMutableComposition and will certainly keep you posted if I have any breakthroughs, or if you do I'm curious to hear! If you could post just the composition part of the code that could be helpful though.

Comment: if I remember well it was a bad timerange issue